# Run MobileFirst7.1 Project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, deployment, ibm-mobilefirst, native

Hello everyone I want to run my MobileFirst (7.1) Project in Android Studio and I see some errors with the gradle compatibility.
I have to Transform the project in to a gradle project, but I don't even know how to do that.
Thank you so much.

Comment: Which version of Android studio you are using?.From  android studio import as a project .

Comment: I am Using 3.1.2 version,the latest version
Thank you

Comment: Android 3.1.2 supports latest gradle version .Change the gradle version in the app to latest version that error shows to update .

Comment: Or use android studio  2.2 or 2.3 older version

Comment: From android studio import it as a gradle project not just open

Comment: Before import the project as gradle,what to do to packaging the project or that level

Answer (score 0):

Android studio does the job of converting. Instead of just using the "Open an existing Android Project" option use the "Import Project (Gradle, Eclipse, ADT etc) " option.